# Can OpenGL Render handle (semi)transparency of an object?

Tags: texturing

[image]
**Update:**  Success with the translucent object under the emitting skydome!

Settings:[image]

I want to make an object glassine, mostly transparent.  Maybe add some partially reflective coating on the top.  Is the OpenGL Render able to do this?

I'd love to try it myself first in order to find out, but every attempt I've made to (a) make something any-alpha at all ends in failure when rendering in OpenGL, and (b) whenever I try to render using anything else, like Cycles, I get no output at all, or the skybox texture isn't rendered at all.  And still no translucency.

Can someone show me how to take a cube (inside of the skydome I've already got), and make it half transparent?  And render okay?  Seems simple, but nothing's simple in Blender.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you tried enabling glsl in the viewport shading property, and then use the opengl viewport rendering icon-button? (textured or material mode)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Whenever I have GLSL enabled, my sky inside the dome disappears, goes white back there.

Comment: But I also don't know where to find an OpenGL rendering icon-button.  I only know of menu Render!OpenGL Render Image.

Comment: I added an answer below to show a possible setup, can't say anything about your "dome"... no details about it?

Comment: Okay, that works for transparency, now I've got that.  Awesome!.  Thank you!  (But darn, my sky is still missing with it switched to GLSL though.  Still can't get that to show.  It's either sky with an opaque object in front of it, or white background with transparency in the object.  One or the other.)

Comment: I meant: put some _visual_ detail in your question (edit using the link just below it), describing how it's done, its materials. If you wish to share a test file, use this servic http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ (free, permanent) and paste the provided link in the question text.

Comment: Okay, I succeeded a few hours later.  Thank you again for all your help.  It ended up that the emitting skydome can coexist with a semi-transparent object underneath it.  (GLSL never worked with the configuration, but Multitexture ended up doing it for both the skydome and the transluscent cube simultaneously.)  I'll post the settings I stumbled upon, but there are so many that it will take some time.

Comment: (Will work on the partial reflectivity next.)

Comment: You got me seeing that the Object parameters have a Transparency setting in addition to the one in Texture parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Her is whay I tried, but I don't know about your dome...

[image]